# How to Group list by last 2 months and count its distinct items in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Good day. I want to group a list by last 2 months and count how many products are their in every month and also count distinct category for every product sold in each month

I have a list. It contains a class named ProductTransaction.

```
List<ProductTransaction> productList = new List<ProductTransaction>();
class ProductTransaction
{

    string product;
    DateTime date_sold;
    string  category;
} 

productList.Add(new ProductTransaction () {product="sword", date_sold=03/05/2017,category="weapons"});
productList.Add(new ProductTransaction() {product="sword2", date_sold=03/01/2017,category="weapons"});
productList.Add(new ProductTransaction() {product="potion", date_sold=02/05/2017,category="life"});
productList.Add(new ProductTransaction() {product="jacket", date_sold=02/03/2017,category="clothing"});
productList.Add(new ProductTransaction() {product="jacketofBear", date_sold=02/01/2017,category="clothing"});
```

I want to achieve a data like below. Please see attached image file

```
Month    --        productCount     --       categoryCount

March    --               2         --              1

February --               3         --              2
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _last two months_?  Are you saying that if your example had more than 2 months represented you'd only want 2, and if so which 2.  Also do you really want to group on only month, or should it take year into account if there are transactions for the same month but different years?

Comment: I want only to get the last 2 months transaction using the date_sold sir. For example, The month now is March then, I want only to get March and February for this year only sir.

Comment: You say "I want" twice. That *sounds* like asking others to write your code. I'm sure you tried yourself, but it would help to know where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First you can calculate the earliest date you want by subtracting the current day from the current date to get the beginning of the current month and then subtracting 1 month to get the beginning of the previous month.  Then you'd use that to filter you collection, then group on the month and select the distinct count of the products and categories.

```
DateTime beginningOfPreviousMonth = DateTime.Today
    .AddDays(-DateTime.Today.Day)
    .AddMonths(-1);
var results = productList.Where(p => p.date_sold.Date >= beginningOfPreviousMonth)
    .GroupBy(p => p.date_sold.Month)
    .Select(grp => new 
    {
        Month = new DateTime(1,key,1).ToString("MMMM"),
        ProductCount = grp.Select(x => x.product).Distinct().Count(),
        CategoryCount = grp.Select(x => x.category).Distinct().Count()
    });

foreach(var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Hi sir, I tried your code but I have difficulties in displaying the data

Comment: @LanceKidd That might be because I didn't actually capture the result.  I've fixed that now.  If that isn't the issue then let me know what is.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProductTransaction.productList = new List<ProductTransaction>() {
               new ProductTransaction () {product="sword", date_sold= DateTime.Parse("03/05/2017"),category="weapons"},
               new ProductTransaction() {product="sword2", date_sold=DateTime.Parse("03/01/2017"),category="weapons"},
               new ProductTransaction() {product="potion", date_sold=DateTime.Parse("02/05/2017"),category="life"},
               new ProductTransaction() {product="jacket", date_sold=DateTime.Parse("02/03/2017"),category="clothing"},
               new ProductTransaction() {product="jacketofBear", date_sold=DateTime.Parse("02/01/2017"),category="clothing"}
            };

            var results = ProductTransaction.productList
                .Where(x => (x.date_sold >= DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017")) && (x.date_sold <= DateTime.Parse("3/31/2017")))
                .GroupBy(x => x.date_sold.Month)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    month = x.Key,
                    year = x.FirstOrDefault().date_sold.Year,
                    category_count = x.GroupBy(y => y.category).Count(),
                    product_count = x.Count()
                }).ToList();
        }
    }

    class ProductTransaction
    {
        public static List<ProductTransaction> productList = new List<ProductTransaction>();

        public string product;
        public DateTime date_sold;
        public string category;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code fragment may answer the OP's question, the answer would be more useful if you'd add an explanation. Note that code-only answers tend to be flagged for quality review, which may cause them to be deleted.

Comment: Hi sir, your code works fine in getting the distinct count for category and count of product but how can I limit it in last 3 months of this year only?

Comment: I added a WHERE to filter results.  See updated code.